# Run python script inside bat script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, virtualenv

I'm wondering about running python script inside bat script. At first, I need to set up virtual environment which set up correctly. The last thing is to run python script. This is my bat file.

```
chdir C:\Projects\bob
start C:\Environments\venv\Scripts\activate
python C:\Projects\bob\main.py
```

Command does not starting the python script

```
python C:\Projects\bob\main.py
```

Comment: So what is your question? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `start` command will run your activation script in a new terminal instance, so your venv will not be active for your next command. Use `call` instead:

```
chdir C:\Projects\bob
call C:\Environments\venv\Scripts\activate
python C:\Projects\bob\main.py
```

Alternatively you could forgo changing directories and calling activate all together, and just call the python executable in your venv directly

```
C:\Environments\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Projects\bob\main.py
```

Comment: Yes, don't bother with activating the virtual environment, in many cases it's not necessary, on the condition of course that you call explicitly the right python binary located inside the virtual environment.